# For an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $\aleph_0 \leq 2^{2^\kappa}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to do a past paper question which states:
$$
\text{For all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, we have } \aleph_0 \leq  2^{2^\kappa}.
$$
I'm supposed to be able to do this without the axiom of choice, but I can't see how. I know that there can be no bijection (or surjection) from any natural number with $X$, where $|X| = \kappa$, but I can't get any further.

A solution or hint would be great, thanks!

EDIT: Something that bugs me about this question is that they've written $\aleph_0 \leq  2^{2^\kappa}$, whereas the solution below using Cantor's theorem shows that $\aleph_0 <  2^{2^\kappa}$, that is strict inequality holds. Is this just a mistake, or to throw people off?

Comment: According to the definition I have, $\kappa$ is finite if there is a bijection $f:n \to X$ for $|X| = \kappa$, and some $n \in \omega$, otherwise $\kappa$ is infinite?

Comment: If you are not assuming the axiom of choice then there are a few different possible inequivalent definitions of "cardinal".  Can you be precise about how it is defined here?

Comment: @Nate: Only one definition of cardinal makes sense when exponentiation is involved, if the axiom of choice is not assumed. (HINT: The axiom of choice is equivalent to saying that for every ordinal $\alpha$, $2^\alpha$ can be well-ordered.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: So, should one read the claim as "for every infinite set $A$, there is an injection from $\aleph_0$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$"?  Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @Nate: Yes, that is correct. (For bonus points, you can actually find an injection from $\Bbb R$ into $\mathcal{P(P(}A))$. And you can still show that the inequality is strict.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:** It suffices to find a surjection from $2^\kappa$ onto the natural numbers, now look at cardinalities of finite sets.

You can also show that equality is never possible. But that is besides the point. You are asked to find an injection, not to prove there are no bijections.

Comment: Thank you very much, the last answer probably confused me more than anything else. I have to admit, I was hoping you would answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: it seems like if I showed $f:2^\kappa \to \omega$ was a surjection, then this doesn't imply $\aleph_0 \leq 2^\kappa$ unless I use the axiom of choice? Am I missing something?

Comment: That is correct. And it is consistent that there is an infinite set $A$ such that $\mathcal P(A)$ does not have a countably infinite subset. But as my hint suggests, there is always a sujrection from $\mathcal P(A)$ onto the natural numbers.

Comment: Also, note that if there is a surjection from $A\to B$, then there is an injection from $B$ into $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Thank you, I just got it! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead In fact, if there is a surjection from $A$ to $B$, then there is an injection from $\mathcal P(B)$ into $\mathcal P(A)$, so you get that $\mathbb R$ injects into $2^{2^\kappa}$.

Comment: @Andres: That is correct. And if we brought this up, we can even show that there is no bijection from $\Bbb R$ to $2^{2^\kappa}$, but that's a more difficult theorem.

Comment: Can we use Cantor's argument ($2^{\mathcal{P}(x)}>x$) to get $2^{2^k}>2^k>k$ and as $k$ is infinite, we'd get $k\geq \omega$ which finishes the proof?

Comment: @asdf: You're assuming choice. If you assume that every infinite cardinal is at least countable, then your proof is practically over. The key point is to prove that even when you have infinite sets which do not have a countably infinite subset, their second power set is at least countable.

Comment: But how does this assume AC? Is it somewhere in the proof of Cantor's theorem?

Comment: @asdf: No, it literally in your statement "as $k$ is infinite, we'd get $k\geq\omega$".

Comment: Hmm, doesn't this follow easier from $k > n$ for every $n \in \omega$ and then saying $k\geq\sup\{n| n \in \omega\}=\omega$?

Comment: @asdf: Not without a bit of choice.