# Inequality about infinite cardinals

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The following is a question I'm interested in solving:

[For an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $\aleph_0 \leq 2^{2^\kappa}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296702/for-an-infinite-cardinal-kappa-aleph-0-leq-22-kappa/1296795?noredirect=1#comment5667885_1296795)

The idea is to solve it without using AC. As @Asaf Karagila pointed out in the comment section:

"Even if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, you can't assume that $\kappa \geq \omega$ without using AC".

I am still trying to think this through: My reasoning being, that as $\kappa > n \forall n \in \omega$, then $\kappa \geq \sup\{n:n\in \omega\}=\omega$ as $\omega$ is a limit ordinal.

Where does my reasoning fail? And also, a detailed solution would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at something else which we can prove by induction: For every $n$ there is a decreasing sequence of natural numbers of length $n$.

Given a sequence of length $n$, shift it all by $1$, and obtain a sequence of length $n+1$. Great!

Does that mean that there is an infinite decreasing sequence of natural numbers? No. Because for different $n$'s, the decreasing sequence is different, and we cannot stitch them together.

The induction only proved that we can find arbitrarily large finite sequences. Not an infinite sequence.

Similarly here, the induction proof only lets you find arbitrarily large finite sets. It does not let you combine them into a countably infinite set, nor it even lets you find a *sequence* of sets of arbitrary sizes.

Answer (score 3):

While we can prove that $\kappa>n$ for all $n\in\omega$ by induction, that induction doesn't carry us any further forward. It takes a weak version of $\mathsf{AC}$ to say that every infinite set has a countably-infinite subset.

Remember that $\kappa>n$ means that there is an injection from $n$ into $\kappa.$ In fact, there are infinitely-many such injections for any such $n,$ if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal. One might think we could use injections $n\hookrightarrow\kappa$ to somehow *build* an injection $\omega\hookrightarrow\kappa,$ but in order to do so, we must make countably-infinitely-many choices. Can't do that without some Choice, since all we know about $\kappa$ is that it is infinite.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. However isn't is true that the inequality between $\kappa$ and the $sup$ should hold? I feel like this is the definition of supremum.

Comment: If we know that $\kappa$ is an **ordinal**, then it holds, but without Choice, not every cardinal is well-orderable.

Comment: @asdf: There is a clash between naive intuition, and mathematical reality. It will happen again, many times over through your life, that you will believe something to be true, and find a contradiction in the mathematical reality. Some people argue that your intuition is correct, which is all the more reason to adopt the axiom of choice as an axiom.

Comment: Yes, having read the comments, it seems like I've used the ordinal properties for cardinals. Thanks a lot! Would appreciate it even more if you could take the time at some point to write down a detailed solution - I think I've started to use the AC subconciously

Comment: @asdf: (1) Glad to help! (2) A detailed solution to what, exactly? (3) You're far from the first to use $\mathsf{AC}$ without meaning to, believe me!

Comment: To the statement that is linked: I started reading the linked question, but couldn't make much of the hint given by @AsafKaragila.

Comment: Why not just ask Asaf in a comment on the linked answer? He certainly has a better idea what he's talking about than I do. :-)

Comment: @asdf: If $X$ is a set of size $\kappa$, map every $n<\omega$ to the set of subsets of $X$ which have exactly $n$ elements. Good?