# Surjection from a powerset onto $\Bbb{N}$ is always possible

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this answer that I can't quite understand:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1296795/431135

It says that, for any infinite set $A$, there is always a surjection from $\cal{P}$$(A)$ onto $\Bbb{N}$. In particular, without using the Axiom of Choice.

Any sub-hint on how to see this hint?

Comment: Even if $A$ is finite?  empty?  But if $A$ is infinite it already contains a subset equivalent to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Right @lulu, I had to specify $A$ infinite. And ok, $A$ has at least a subset in bijection with $\Bbb N$, but then that's just an element of $\cal{P}$$(A)$...

Comment: What's unclear about consider the cardinalities of finite sets?

Comment: The point of Asaf's comment is that, provably in ZF, if $A$ is infinite, then for any finite $n$, $A$ has a subset of size $n$. Perhaps you may want to prove this first.

Comment: Each element of that countably infinite subset is an element of $\mathscr P(A)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid using the axiom of choice, define a map $f\colon P(A) \to \mathbb{N}$ by 
$f(S) = n \iff |S| = n.$ Since $A$ is infinite, it has subsets of all finite cardinalities. Thus $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I like this explicit function, but are you entirely sure you're not using the axiom of choice? Since $A$ is infinite, then it is not in bijection with any $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Does this mean that for each $n$ there's a subset of $A$ of size $n$? It feels like there is an hidden choice function there..

Comment: @Davide: The axiom of choice is not needed to prove this. A set is infinite if and only if it has arbitrarily large finite sets.

Comment: If you want, you can prove that more rigorously by induction.

Comment: My definition of infinite set is "a set not in bijection with any $n\in\Bbb{N}$". Which I guess I can interpret as "for any $n$ I can inject $n$ into my infinite set". Thanks, I think now I convinced myself, I just never thought of a way to show an intuitively obvious fact like this.

Comment: @Davide: The point is that by induction, as Mark mentioned, you can prove that any set is comparable with any finite cardinal. So it is finite if and only if the induction "gets stuck" at some point and the set is finite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If we get into this, I have to ask: what kind of induction are you referring to? I guess not ordinal induction, as we would need WO. So would you induce with respect to $n$? Say the statement "any set has cardinality comparable with $n$"?

Comment: @Davide: Induction. If $A$ is infinite and $B$ is a subset of $A$ of size $n$, then because $A$ is infinite $A\neq B$. Choose $a\in A\setminus B$, then $B\cup\{a\}$ has $n+1$ subsets. We didn't use AC because we were given $A$ and only made one choice, $a$.

Comment: @Davide, also "ordinal induction" is still valid without choice. The ordinals are well-ordered by definition (or construction?). Since we are talking about the natural numbers here, this is really just good old induction as you learn in your first year of mathematics.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila, now it is clear that you don't use AC in the inductive step

Comment: I realized that my answer is not defined for infinite subsets of $A$. To fix this, send all infinite subsets of $A$ to your favorite natural number.